# scanf taking value of a struct element giving seg fault in C linux

Tags: c, linux, structure

my scanf statement is giving seg fault. could you please tell me why?

```
typedef struct message1
{
    int call_id1;
    int lac;
    long int attribute;
    int conn_id;
    struct message1 *next1;
}M1;
M1 *last=NULL;
main()
{
    printf("\nEnter Call Id\t");
    scanf("%d",&last->call_id1);
}
```

Comment: The actual area is not secured.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY could you please explain your answer and tell me the alternative to above prob.

Comment: Do you think what this ? `(NULL)->call_id1`

Comment: @Arjun Sreedharan  The `&` is not for `last`, but for `last->call_id1` where `&` is needed.

Comment: Minor: given the various styles of allocating memory in the answers, suggest the style of `M1 *last = malloc(sizeof *last);` easiest to write, maintain and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously ... it is not initialized to a proper value:

```
M1 *last=NULL;
```

should be

```
M1 *last= (M1*)malloc(sizeof(M1));
```

Comment: yeah!! thanx.. this was the prob.

Answer (score 2):

your trying to read into a struct which is not allocated memory

add

> M1 *last = malloc(sizeof(struct message1)); // in global space

or

> last =malloc(sizeof(struct message1));  // in main function

Answer (score 2):

Because you initialized your structure pointer with NULL.

```
M1 last;
```

is enough.

No need to give any pointer. If you wish to give it as pointer then use malloc

```
M1 *last;
last = malloc(sizeof(M1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated memory for struct `M1` and trying to access its memory contents which is the reason for segmentation fault,

Allocate memory dynamically as, `M1 *last = malloc(sizeof(M1));`

Comment: you need the `&` too. When you create the structure, the member will have it's own address, and you want to read into that address, not the random value interpreted as address the member points to!

Comment: Sorry, but `scanf("%d",&last->call_id1);` is correct.